# Why does Firefox interpret top offset differently from Chrome, Safari and IE?

Tags: css, firefox, css-float, css-position

Take the following example:

[image]

This is a textarea, with a background image (the grey bar) and a relative positioned div after the textarea with a top offset to move the text in place.

The Markup:

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="6" class="some_textarea">Hello</textarea>
<div class="message_text">This is a message</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.some_textarea {
  background: transparent url(gray_bar.png) repeat-x 50% 100%;
  width: 99%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
}

.message_text {
  display: inline;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -21px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}
```

The problem is that Firefox is the only browser that doesn't agree with the offset, and results in this very small pixel pushing annoyance:

[image]

What is causing this? How can I fix this for consistency? What non-clunky workarounds exist if it can't be fixed?

Comment: How about specifying cols and rows attributes? It made your textarea look the same for me in newest FF/Chrome versions. Default size of textarea elements seems to be different in those browsers.

Comment: I did try explicitly setting width and height using CSS. The textarea does actually have rows and cols, but I forgot to include them in the example. I've updated - but in either case this didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: See this: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/maHkr/7/

---

How about something like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/maHkr/2/

What I did was wrap your textarea/message combo in a relatively positioned `div` and then absolutely positioned the message to the bottom left. You can play round with the exact positioning/margins/paddings to get it looking good across the browsers.

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: This seems to shift the offset problem from top, to bottom. For example, try that Fiddle with a padding on the `.message_text` of `0 6px 8px 6px` and you'll see differences in Firefox compared to other browsers.

Comment: check out the update. it looks pretty nice for me. which version of ff are you running?

Comment: Excellent, that seems to have done it - thanks. Latest public version of Firefox, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery(window).load() instead of jQuery(document).ready()